# GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: No value present in Athena

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena

I tried to query my data with this setup

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `tableName`(
  `accountidalt` string,
  `activitytype` string,
  `alias` string,
  `backuptaskid` string,
  `batchid` string,
  `endpoint` string,
  `error` string,
  `execdatetime` timestamp,
  `extendedauditinfo` struct<ExportDestination:string,RestoreDestination:string,RestoreSource:string,SnapshotDate:bigint,TaskCreateDate:timestamp>,
  `externalid` string,
  `performedby` string,
  `region` string,
  `subsourcedetails` array<struct<DataAmount:struct<MDSize1:bigint,MDSize2:bigint,NetSize1:bigint,NetSize2:bigint,Selector:tinyint,Size1:bigint,Size2:bigint>,DeltaDataSize:bigint,EntitesCounter:int,ExecDuration:int,ExecutionStatus:string,SubTaskSource:string,TaskExecDateTime:timestamp>>,
  `targetaccount` string,
  `taskidalt` string,
  `tasksource` string,
  `tasktype` string,
  `type` string,
  `useridalt` string,
  `id2` string)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `userid` string,
  `taskid` string,
  `accountid` string,
  `month` int,
  `year` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucketName/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false',
  'projection.accountid.type'='inject',
  'projection.enabled'='true',
  'projection.month.digits'='2',
  'projection.month.range'='1,12',
  'projection.month.type'='integer',
  'projection.taskid.type'='inject',
  'projection.userid.type'='inject',
  'projection.year.range'='2018,2051',
  'projection.year.type'='integer',
  'storage.location.template'='s3://bucket-name/userid=${userid}/taskid=${taskid}/accountid=${accountid}/month=${month}-${year}/',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1640094578')
```

This is the select I tried

```
SELECT alias
  FROM "audits"."tableName"
  where userid = '1b17397a-8d72-4910-b9ad-fd059a6c3258' and taskid='9edb7dbf-49c3-41fd-9e10-5e1df07656c3' and accountid = 'aaaBBBBB@abc.org'
  and "month" = 12 and "year" = 2020
```

this is my file location

3://bucketName/userid=1b17397a-8d72-4910-b9ad-fd059a6c3258/taskid=9edb7dbf-49c3-41fd-9e10-5e1df07656c3/accountid= aaaBBBBB @abc.org'/month=12-2020/

after failing, tried to create partition

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD
  PARTITION (userid = '1b17397a-8d72-4910-b9ad-fd059a6c3258' , taskid='9edb7dbf-49c3-41fd-9e10-5e1df07656c3' , accountid = ‘aaaBBBBB @abc.org',
  month = 12 ,  year = 2020) LOCATION 's3://bucketName/userid=1b17397a-8d72-4910-b9ad-fd059a6c3258/taskid=9edb7dbf-49c3-41fd-9e10-5e1df07656c3/accountid=svcCAOD4B@eagle.org/month=12-2020/';
```

I am sure I have data in the location

Got **GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: No value present**

Same question was asked, but this setup is after applying recomendation from the answer

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that had this kind of problem, I had a typo in:

```
'projection.taskid.type'='inject'
```

(All off them)

This should be `injected`.

I suspect that the error will be the same for other types of wrong types.